# Cleaning SSD with live DVD

Tags: boot, ssd

I would like to completely clean/delete a SSD Drive using Ubuntu 18.04 installation DVD.

I put the SSD into my laptop und start from DVD. In the live session I choose the disk application and delete the dev/sda.

When I start the PC grub rescue is entered. When I start the PC without the SSD no grub appears. Is seems to me that still some Linux data is on the SSD. I want a completely clean SSD without any grub stuff or any other data on it.

Comment: 1. You can install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) into the live system (yes, it works but after reboot it will be gone). Then you can use mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus to 'wipe the whole device'; 2. A more advanced alternative (better but maybe more difficult and more risky) is to use `hdparm` with the option `--security-erase`.

Comment: What I do not understand is why grub rescue appears on boot? When I delete the partition dev/sda it should be deleted. It appears also as no file system in Ubuntu live session.

Comment: I think you have deleted, maybe also wiped (overwritten with zeros), a **partition**. But grub (for BIOS mode in an MSDOS partition table) is installed at the head end (in the first mibibyte) in front of the partition(s).

Comment: Is there any chance to wipe it out completely? Without installing any additional programs?

Comment: Yes. You need not install anything to run `hdparm`. And you might be able to use Disks for this purpose. It is also possible to use `shred`, but you may be prompted to overwrite several times which is really a waste of time and unnecessary wear of the memory cells. (But I think the safest and most direct way is to install mkusb and use it for this purpose. You can copy and paste commands from the mkusb help page into a command line window, and when installed it is very easy to use.)